# Compare two arrays and remove the item if matched

Tags: javascript, angular

Could you please suggest a way to compare the two arrays and remove an item from array 2 if code, codename, and itemCode match, any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

List of Array 1 Object

```
[
    {
      “error”: {
        "code": "1",
        "codeName": "test",
        "itemCode": "1"

    }
}
 ]
```

List of Array 2 Object

```
[
  {
    "code": "1",
    "list": [
      {
        "itemCode": "1",
        "orders": [
          {
            "codeName": "test",
            
          },
          {
            "codeName": "tester",
            
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "itemCode": "3",
        "orders": [
          {
            "codeName": "testing",          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected Output after comparing two arrays and matching

```
[
  {
    "code": "1",
    "list": [
      {
        "itemCode": "1",
        "orders": [
        
          {
            "codeName": "tester",
            
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "itemCode": "3",
        "orders": [
          {
            "codeName": "testing",          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

this is what I was tried so far

```
Array1!.map(val1=> {
  Array2?.map(val2 => {
    if (val1.code === val2.code) {
     val2.list.map(item=>{
       if(item.itemCode === val2.itemCode){
        item.orders.map(order=>{
          if(order.codeName === val2.codeName){
            //splice
          }
        })
       }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, your `array2` and expected output seems to be identical. Have a look at `filter()` and `every()` array functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create a map of the original array with the keys necessary for performance reasons, then we can simply loop through the second array and filter out values that match the keys set in the mapping of the previous array!

```js
const arr1 = [{
  error: {
    "code": "1",
    "codeName": "test",
    "itemCode": "1"

  }
}];

const arr2 = [{
  "code": "1",
  "list": [{
      "itemCode": "1",
      "orders": [{
          "codeName": "test",

        },
        {
          "codeName": "tester",

        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "itemCode": "3",
      "orders": [{
        "codeName": "testing",
      }]
    }
  ]
}]
const tracker = {}
const convertArrayToMap = arr1.forEach(x => {
  const key = `${x.error.code}-${x.error.itemCode}-${x.error.codeName}`;
  if (!tracker[key]) {
    tracker[key] = true;
  }
});
const output = arr2.map(x => {
  x.list.forEach(d => {
    d.orders = d.orders.filter(item => !tracker[`${x.code}-${d.itemCode}-${item.codeName}`]);
  });
  return x;
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: You are using your map like a record, not a map. The code works, but it would be better if you either used `map.get` & `map.set`, or used a plain object instead of a map.

Comment: @JSmart523 I wanted to say hashmap, but people get mad for some reason :p

Comment: :-) It's not just naming it. See [https://dev.to/katkelly/advantages-of-a-javascript-map-cen](https://dev.to/katkelly/advantages-of-a-javascript-map-cen). Rather than take advantage of what maps offer, you are setting the *properties* of an object that just happens to be a Map object.

Comment: @JSmart523 Is get and set working of map also O(n) complexity the same as object property get?

Comment: I don't know. I assume so because it *should* be optimized that way, and is said to be better when adding/removing many values. (Something to do with how the object key index is maintained vs how map index is maintained.) Plus, maps can use numbers and objects as keys, not just strings and symbols.